# BTRFS size on disk 200x larger than actual size

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba, disk-space, btrfs

Why is BTRFS so grossly misquoting the size of small files on my filesystem?

```bsh
[pi@rpi scipy]% cat __init__.py | wc -c            # literal byte count
4729
[pi@rpi scipy]% du --apparent-size -h __init__.py  # size on filesystem (same)
4.7K    __init__.py
[pi@rpi scipy]% du -h __init__.py                  # reported size to ls
1.0M    __init__.py
```

- Completely stock options (`defaults`, plain `mkfs.btrfs`)
- Linux Kernel 3.18
- RAID1

---

Okay, so it appaears that BTRFS is rounding files up to 1MB at some threshold. That 1MB is *exactly* 1048576 (or 2²⁰) bytes.

More surprisingly, `cat __init__.py > __init__2.py` makes a new file of the correct size. Does this have something to do with the fact that I created these files over samba?

Newly created files also have the correct size.

Comment: Third file is \_\_init\_\_.pyc. The first two seem correct.

Comment: Sure, but all small files in the filesystem weigh in at 1.0M, so that's unfortunately not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out just rewriting all of the files in-place:

```bash
find . -type f -exec /usr/bin/echo {} \; -exec sed -i '' {} \;
```

Correctly shrank the files. I haven't seen it happen again.